# Sync settings between CLion and ReSharper

Tags: resharper, clion, jetbrains-ide

I am used to CLion in the past, and now I want to try ReSharper. Can I sync the settings of Clion to ReSharper?

CLion can export settings into `clion-settings.zip`, but ReSharper expects to import from `.DotSettings`.

How to set ReSharper's settings by using the settings from CLion?

Comment: I removed your second question as you should only be asking one question at a time and the second question was subjective.

Answer (score 2):

You can't, they are two different products. Some of their features may overlap with each other but their settings will be very different. You will need to configure ReSharper's settings to match your CLion ones manually.